# how to prevent opening another tab in same browser session with php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

I would like to know how i can prevent users from opening a new tab while he/she still open the previous browser instance?

My purpose is to prevent from overriding the data.
For example, if the users open a new tab within same application, I want to prompt the message like

"You are trying to open a new active window within same application.Please close previous window."

Is there any way to do it with php, javascript, session or cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with session info in PHP I think... when a user opens a tab, add to the session what tab it is. And if it's already have loaded that tab, ask the question. The tricky part is to know when the user has stopped using your app or just idling.

You can never prevent a user from opening a new tab in their browser, but you can prevent info from your app to getting to the user. You could work with cookies also, but I see no point if it doesn't need to be remembered longer than the session.

You could also look at HTML5 web storage if you want to make the check with JavaScript instead of PHP. It will work with IE8 and above. It's kind just a key/value database.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's the same browser window, you cannot say if user opened a new tab, or just loaded the page on the same one. Even in `private mode` or `incognio mode`, tabs share sessions.

Sessions depends on cookies, where cookies can be more persistent than sessions. Same issue.

What you can do, is to prevent user to logging again while his previous session is still valid, but this will work when user opens new browser window (or different browser) and tries to log in.

Comment: The following link shows how to track it https://sites.google.com/site/sarittechworld/track-client-windows but I'm not familiar with .Net. According to his solution, I think PHP might has solution as well.

Comment: Yes, that can work, but you need to ask yourself a question. Is this security matter? Because using JavaScript for security is bad. Everyone (especially those who want to break through security) can manipulate or disable JavaScript (and cookies). Relying on that is bad idea. If it's not for security, then go ahead and do what it's said under the link (TL;DR; - set cookie, in PHP if cookie is set then dont show content, on JS event "onbeforeunload" delete the cookie.).